# Как сделать, чтобы текст вращался внутри круга при нажатии на кнопку в WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

у меня не получается сделать, чтобы текст крутился внутри этого круга, при нажатии на кнопку, как можно это сделать?
Есть кнопка play, при нажатии на нее, текст , который будет находится на этом изображении, должен крутиться, по кругу от центра изображения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вы как пробовали то? Покажите то, что уже имеете и как пытались.

Comment: Есть кнопка play, этот круг(изображение), TextBox, нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку play, TextBox крутился по часовой от центра изображения, рандомный промежуток времени

Comment: Это вы описали задачу, но не показали ваши наработки. Вы ведь должны понять как это делается, мы должны понять ваш уровень и на что способны, а как это можно все понять, если вы не показываете свои наработки? Или вы хотите, что бы мы сделали за вас готовенькое, вы скопировали в проект и забили на это дело?

Comment: Я знаю, то что надо делать через Angle... Центр поменял у TextBox. А как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку крутилось на рандомное число градусов, у меня не получается